# Validate an item in `object` based on another item in the same `object`

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

[Reproducible at https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net - just copy and paste the JSON objects (minding that the first one is an example)]

So, I expect a JSON object like this:

```
[
    {"k": "my_date", "v": "2021-08-04"},
    {"k": "item_1", "v": 1},
    {"k": "item_2", "v": 2.5},
    ...
    {"k": ".+", "v": <<type - number>>}
]
```

I want to design a JSON schema that ensures "my_date" is always a `string`, but all other items (whatever their "k" value) are numbers.

What I have now is

```
{
  "$id": "#/properties/my-output",
  "type": "array",
  "title": "The Output Schema",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "k": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "v": {
        "type": "number"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but this obviously doesn't work, since

```
[
  {
    "k": "my_date",
    "v": "2021-08-04"
  },
  {
    "k": "any_name",
    "v": 123.2
  },
  {
    "sdf": "sdf"
  }
]
```

fails, because:

1. `my_date` has value which is `string` and this is not permitted by the schema;
2. `sdf` should not be here at all, but the schema accepts it.

How should I design the schema?

P.S. I expect that there would be other "k" values which should have `string`s as "v" values, so I'd like to be able to address these.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the use of the extra "sdf" property with `"additionalProperties": false` (adjacent to the "properties" keyword).  see https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#additional-properties

As for your dates, you seem to be saying they both can and cannot be strings, so I'm not sure what the actual issue is there.

Answer (score 0):

So, one approach would be to make use of "oneOf" for the schema of the items in the array.

```
{
   "type": "object",
    "required": ["k", "v"],
      "properties": {
        "k": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "v": {}
      },
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "oneOf": [
      {"$ref": "#/$defs/dateValue"},
      {"$ref": "#/$defs/anyOtherValue"}
    ],
    "$defs":{
      "dateValue": {
          "properties": {
            "k": {
              "const": "my_date"
            },
           "v": { "type": "string" }
          },
          "additionalProperties": false
      },
      "anyOtherValue": {
          "not": {
            "properties": {
              "k": {
                "enum": ["my_date"]
              }
            }
         }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: (The advantage of this approach is that you can easily extend it to additional keyed types by adding the specific schema to the "oneOf" list, along with the value of the key to the "enum" list in the "any other value.)

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the answer is using if-else-then statement, like this (thanks @Ether for suggesting using `additionalProperties`):

```
{
  "$id": "#/properties/my-output",
  "type": "array",
  "title": "The Output Schema",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
      "k": {
        "type": "string",
      },
      "v": {
      }
    },
    "if": {
      "properties": {
        "k": {
          "enum": ["my_date"]
        }
      }
    },
    "then": {
      "properties": {
        "v": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "else": {
      "properties": {
        "v": {
          "type": "number"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What happens here is the following:
Initially, we want an item in the array to have `k` value and `v` value. `k` value is constrained to be a string - always; but we don't specify constraints for `v`... yet.

Then, we explicitly specify our constraints: If `k` is one of `"enum":["my_date", <<add others here>>]`, then we want the type of that `k` to be `string`. Else - we want a number.

The above schema correctly fails on the following test input (which you can try on https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net):

```
[
  {
    "k": "my_date",
    "v": "2021-08-04"
  },
  {
    "k": "my_date_wrong",
    "v": "2021-08-04"
  },
  {
    "k": "some_item",
    "v": 123.2
  },
  {
    "k": "some_other_123item",
    "v": 123.2
  },
  {
    "sdf": "sdf"
  }
]
```

The above input correctly fails on `"k": "my_date_wrong"`, because it is not included in the `enum` in the if-statement. It also correctly fails on the `sdf` field, since it is invalidated by `additionalProperties`.

The obvious downside of this approach is that if you have many `v`-s that must be strings, you need to explicitly enumerate them in the if-statement.